# Cumulative sum on list

Tags: python, arraylist

I am a beginner in python programming. I am trying to perform cumulative addition on values of a list.

```
values=[1,2,3]
for i in range(len(values)):
    print(sum(values[0:i]))
```

Output is

```
0
1
3
```

Whereas I am expecting a list with output [1,3,6]

Please can you someone guide me which part of my code is wrong? I don't wish to use accumulate() function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How slicing in Python works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)

Comment: did you try to ``print(values[0:i])`` to see what is going on in your code? That would immensly help!

Comment: What is I in your code? You mixed **i** and **I**.

Comment: Indexing in Python lists is from start (inclusive) to end (***exclusive***)

Comment: @Wimanicesir it was _i_ before someone edited the question

Comment: Yes, it was cleared. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use walrus operator for python 3.8+

```
values=[1,2,3]
v=0
[v := v + n for n in values]

#output
[1, 3, 6]
```

Your corrected code should be from `1` to `len(values)+1`:

```
values=[1,2,3]
for i in range(1,len(values)+1):
    print(sum(values[0:i]))
1
3
6
```

Link : python-range

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/range.html

Comment: @suganyathangappan if you find the answer useful you can +1✔️